# Asterisk CSS rule error

Tags: css, syntax, aptana, aptana3

Some time ago I found this code in a highly upvoted answer:

```
[class*="col-"] {
  ...
}
```

Aptana Studio gives me this error:

> Syntax Error: unexpected token "*"

So, is it really an error? I mean I found it in an answer with so many upvotes.

I tried to convince myself to let go of the red marking in my project and I did fine for almost a week, but I couldn't help myself from asking... :)

Comment: Asking … what? You've made a couple of statements, but there's no question here.

Comment: @Quentin missed that. Updated, thank you very much.

Comment: @prodigitalson that could be an answer. I will search a bit on why Aptana got confused and update if needed.

Comment: Presumably Aptana's CSS parser is out of date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't an error. See [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors):

> `[att*=val]`
>   Represents an element with the att attribute whose value contains at least one instance of the substring "val". If "val" is the empty string then the selector does not represent anything.

Comment: I see Quentin. Any thoughts on why Aptana may have been confused with that? I get the same error in a similar rule.

Comment: Presumably Aptana's CSS parser is out of date.